Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' on prisma.service
import { INestApplication, Injectable, OnModuleInit } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
    console.log("postgresql connected");
  }

  async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.$on("beforeExit", async () => {
      await app.close();
    });
  }
}

The error is here   this.$on("beforeExit", async () => {
I tried various solutions to resolve the issue, to run npx prisma generate, or update the package but any of this didn't work.
Any ideeas?

The beforeExit hook has been removed from the library query engine, read more here. They have an upgrade guide that may be helpful. This is the Prisma ORM 4 code they give as an example:
const exitHandler = () => {
  // your exit handler code
}

prisma.$on('beforeExit', exitHandler)

which would now not work because of this breaking change. They replaced it with
const exitHandler = () => {
  // your exit handler code
}

process.on('exit', exitHandler)
process.on('beforeExit', exitHandler)
process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler)
process.on('SIGTERM', exitHandler)
process.on('SIGUSR2', exitHandler)

They also recommend to remove the custom enableShutdownHooks methods in your service.
